# How to fix nav and scroll main?

Tags: html, css

what I wanted is to make a design so that the *nav* remains fixed on top and *main* scroll. So when I gave position fixed to *nav*, it fixed its position, and the *main* shifted at the bottom of the *nav*. So to make *main* visible I gave `margin-top 60px`. But It shifts complete *div* instead *main*. I want to know what breaks my design and how to fix it.

https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/qBaoZYx?editors=1100

**html**

```html
<div>
    <nav> navigation </nav>
    <main> main content </main>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: seagreen;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put  in nav element  ,  top:0;   and will worked

```css
html {
}

body {
overflow:hidden;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: seagreen;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;

  top:0;
}

main{  
  overflow-y:scroll!important;
  width:auto;
 height:700px;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav> navigation </nav>
  <main> main content </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, Really appreciate that. 
That works but the scroll bar comes on the complete page not just on the main.

Comment: i updated the code, this should be work,

Comment: i set a height :600px; to main element,   i also removed  margin, but  later you can add this

Answer (score 1):

To do what you try to do according to the comments (having only the scrollbar for the main-content you can use flexbox and CSS-Grid. I have a solution with using CSS-Grid. You declare the body as `box-sizing: border-box;` and set a definite height of `height: 100vh;` to span the entire browser height. Same for width with `width: 100vw;`. Then you use 2 rows by using `grid-template-rows: 60px auto;`. Thatw ay, the first element (the navbar) will be 60px height and the `main` content be the entire remaining height of the browser. Last but not least you add an overflow rule to the `main` content with `overflow-y: auto;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </main>
</body>
```

As you cant use grid: You can also do it without grid, however it is more tricky. You can use the calc function to make the height of the content as heigh as the remaining viewport height with `height: calc(100vh - 60px); as in the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't use grid. I've to use flexbox only. Thanks for your answer. 

Comment: @DeC I adjusted to your requirements